# $cacheFactory + API calls: Updating Cache

Tags: angularjs, caching

My API calls are automatically being cached in the default cache provided by $cacheFactory (`{cache: true}`). If I add another record to the DB I want to be able to add the relevant information (which is returned from the post API call to add the record) to the cached information I have rather than deleting the cache and having it re-request all the data.

```
  var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
  var data = $httpDefaultCache.get(key)
```

The key is the path of my API request. Data is just an array. Element 1 is my stored data which is a hash containing arrays. I planned to simply add to it my new record. However when I retrieve it (`$httpDefaultCache.get(key)[1]`), I don't get a hash. I get a string. I could just take said string and transform it into a hash or simply add to the string, but I think I'm missing a key component of retrieving data from the cache. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer of how I went forward in case anyone runs into a similar problem.

Let's say you used $http to make a get request to an API with cache set to true.

Set the return value of this request within your controller to whatever; we'll use $scope.politicians.

Since we used the default cache, we can retrieve it by `$cacheFactory.get('$http')(cachedUrl)`.

Remove the cache by doing `$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(urlOfGetRequest)`

Make any changes I want to the $scope value that was initially set to the return value from the API call and then reset the cache to that scope when finished.

```
$scope.politicians[new-key] = new-value;
```

Set the cache again, but use your scope as the value.

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').put(urlOfGetRequest, $scope.politicians);
```

Using the non-default cache makes this process rather easier.

I swear there must be a more direct way of doing this. But I could not find it.

Comment: thanks. it works for me.. Do you got any other way ?